# Need help in understand basic Objective-c Like methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to objective-c. It is even hard for me to understand how to write the methods given in Apple documentation. As I am a beginner I need suggestion from people who can understand my situation. I want to become a IPhone application developer.

Answer (score 1):

Give me your mail id, I will forward you some reading material. First you need to learn Objective-C, not in details, but basic syntax atleast. Then you move to simple Hello World iPhone Application. You will pick up soon then.
Objective C reference links -

[Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)

[Objective C tutorial](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html)

For iPhone Programming you can refer following blogs- 
iCode, 
iphonedevelopment.blogspot,

http://ved-dimensions.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2009-01-20T06%3A39%3A00-08%3A00&max-results=5

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but the point of this site is to provide answers useful to everyone. "Give me your email" is doesn't help Joe Googlesearcher three years from now.

Comment: agreed Chuck. Sorry for not thinking that way. I will upload some useful docs and post the link here. :)

Comment: EDIT- I am not having material regarding iOS4, but the blogs pasted in my code, if followed and having apple documentation should not create any problem. Here is iPhone Reading Material for Beginners - http://www.box.net/shared/ncznmzm7qk

Comment: Thank you all of you for taking time to help me. Never expected so much great people are there for helping purpose. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start is with Stanford's [Developing Apps for iOS](http://tinyurl.com/25rah8e) course.

Answer (score 1):

### Apple-provided documentation:

- [Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneGeneral/index.html)
- [Your First iOS Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html)
- [Getting Started with iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163)
- [iOS Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)
- [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Table View Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

### iTunes U

- [iTunes U: Stanford — Developing Apps for iOS by Paul Hegarty](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=395605774)
- [iTunes U: Stanford — iPhone Application Development by Alan Cannistraro and Josh Shaffer](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/iphone-application-development/id384233225)
- [Apple's WWDC10 Session Videos](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092414) <sub>(apple developer login required)</sub>

Comment: thank you very much for ur help.It was really a honour for me to get help from u. It was really a great help from u sir. I don't know how to thank u and all others but at present I have only these meaningful words foe u all.

Comment: To thank us, you could vote helpful answers up (by clicking arrows) and accept the best one (by clicking checkmark).